# how to sort nested list without using optional argument `key`

Tags: python, list, sorting, for-loop, tuples

im sort of stuck on a homework question.
Suppose I have a list as such:

`[('Paul George', 1), ('Luke Skywalker', 2), ('Mitchell Piker', 3), ('Phil Dam', 1)]`

I have to write a function such that the list will be ordered by the second element , which is the integer value. Also, if two people have the same integer, then i have to sort alphabetically. Also, i am allowed to use `sort` but i cannot use the optional argument, `key`. So i should have something like this:

`[('Mitchell Piker', 3), ('Luke Skywalker', 2), ('Paul George', 1), ('Phil Dam', 1)]`

```
>>> def sort(lst: List[Tuple[str, int]]):
    """Return the list of tuples from largest integer score to lowest 
    integer score. If two people have the same score, then sort them by 
    alphabetical order.
    """
    lst2 = []
    lst2.append(lst[0])
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for j in range(len(lst2)):
            if lst[i][-1] > lst2[j][-1] and lst[i][-1] not in lst2:
                lst2.insert(0, lst2[i])
            if lst[i][-1] < lst2[j][-1] and lst[i][-1] not in lst2:
                lst2.append(lst2[i][-1])
    return lst2
```

however i get an error. Can anyone help? Thank you very much

Comment: `lst: List(Tuple(str, int))` ?

Comment: @alfasin Noticed Later. Deleted already. :).

Comment: "i get an error" Please share that error in your post...

Answer (score 1):

If it can be assumed that the numbers are going to be always integers, you can use them to index the values, like this (it could also be achieved with sort instead of sorted)

```
groups = defaultdict(list)
max_id = -1
for name, idx in lst:
    groups[idx].append(name)
    if max_id < idx:
        max_id = idx
result = [(name, idx) for idx in range(max_id, -1, -1) for name in sorted(groups.get(idx, []))]
# [('Mitchell Piker', 3), ('Luke Skywalker', 2), ('Paul George', 1), ('Phil Dam', 1)]
```

EDIT:

```
from collections import defaultdict
groups = defaultdict(list)
for name, idx in lst:
    groups[idx].append(name)
[(name, idx) for idx in sorted(groups.keys())[::-1] for name in sorted(groups[idx])]
```

Note: if you are against using `groups.keys()` you can always use `[x for x in groups]` instead...

Comment: Small modification will make it handle any number (not just `int`) and in a arguably cleaner way: see edit

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the signature of the function is something that was messed up only in the question (otherwise the code will raise a `NameError`:

The issue is because of this line:

```
for j in range(len(lst2))
```

the length of `lst2` is zero - the loop is never executed...

Comment: sorry i forgot to type up lst2.append(lst[0]). the question has been edited. sorry about the confusion

Comment: @DWCY that doesn't change the issue

Answer (score 0):

What about that?

```
lst = [('Paul George', 1), ('Luke Skywalker', 2), ('Mitchell Piker', 3), ('Phil Dam', 1)]

[(n,-i) for (i,n) in sorted([(-i,n) for (n,i) in lst])]


[('Mitchell Piker', 3),
 ('Luke Skywalker', 2),
 ('Paul George', 1),
 ('Phil Dam', 1)]
```

Explanation: `sorted` does what you want except that:

- it will sort according to first element (name) first
- then sort according to second element (number) but in ascending order too

So to hack around that: sandwich it with element swapping as well as negating the number.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

just for test_case, I have edited the name for more accuracy:

```
your_data=[('Paul George', 1), ('Luke Skywalker', 2), ('Mitchell Piker', 3), ('Ahil Dam', 1)]

new={}
for item in your_data:
    if item[1] not in new:
        new[item[1]]=[item[0]]
    else:
        new[item[1]].append(item[0])


    for key,value in new.items():
        if len(value)>1:

            new[key]=sorted(value)



final_list=[]
for key,value in new.items():
    if len(value) > 1:
        for sub_item in value:
            final_list.append((sub_item,key))
    else:
        final_list.append(("".join(value),key))


print(final_list)
```

output:

```
[('Ahil Dam', 1), ('Paul George', 1), ('Luke Skywalker', 2), ('Mitchell Piker', 3)]
```

or if you want result like that then just reverse the final result:

```
print(final_list[::-1])
```